# Raspberry Pi's Power LED does not light, heat and no boot!

Tags: power, boot-issues

I was using my raspberry pi and was testing a piece of code, what I wanted to happen happened, however immediately afterwards the Pi stopped working. Now, when I give the Pi power, the red (power) LED does not turn on (not even for a little bit) and there is a permanent green light followed by the blinking of the green light (this blinking comes in a regular pattern. There is also a lot of heat coming from the central component.
The Pi was working for a month, and I have not changed how I supply it power, and now even when I detach all of the components, the Pi will not boot.
I have checked to see if the SD card is correctly placed.
I would appreciate any help, however can you please mention any possible solutions besides replacing the Pi.

Comment: This question is open ended. Its a text book example of how NOT to use Stack Exchange. A ton of downvoted answers, more deleted answers, upset people and worst of all. NO ACCEPTED ANSWER! -1

Comment: @ppumkin I can't disagree with you, but what is the value of resurrecting this after 18 months?

Comment: I bought one off of EBAY that was made in China. Unfortunately, it only lasts two years.

Answer (score 3):

Red LED not lighting up means the supply voltage never exceeds 4.65V. This is consistent with "a lot of heat coming from the central component", which is no good news. In the best case, your SD card is sinking abnormal current, heating up the chip as well. In the worst case, the chip itself is damaged.

Blinking of the green LED means failure to read the SD card, which is good news, meaning probably only the card is broken, not the RPi itself. You should buy a new SD card, flash the system on it and try to boot. Don't try to reuse the broken SD card - depending of the kind of damage it has, it may cost you whatever equipment you plug it into.

EDIT: try powering your RPi with SD card unplugged. It won't boot of course, but a healthy device should at least have the red LED on.

Comment: Was using a slave usb port, changed it to a usb plug and all working....worked for me....

Answer (score 0):

I've found when the green led blinks regularly, about .500ms it indicates it is not finding the operating system...I'm sure your best off re-writing your SD card.

Comment: Where did you find this info? I have a different [source](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=8725) which says: "3 flashes: loader.bin not found, 4 flashes: loader.bin not launched, 5 flashes: start.elf not found, 6 flashes: start.elf not launched".

Answer (score 0):

One of the following things is broken, test in this order.

- System/sd card (unlikely but easiest tested - reinstall on sd-card, replace sd card)
- Power supply (replace with other supply)
- Pi itself :(

Answer (score 0):

My apologies for not answering to those that commented on this thread. ( I can't comment on answers anyway due to low reps).

I am replying this as I wish to close this thread. I believe from memory that I bought a new Raspberry PI and assume the old one to be dead.

Fast forward today, as I was looking at my old Raspberry PI thread, I tried to powered the old one I had today(2017,Oct) =( No LED lighting up this time around. It is officially dead.

Answer (score -2):

If the red LED never comes on, then maybe it has failed in some way.  Like in jetliners where the landing gear light fails so everybody panics until the Air Force looks and can see the gear is actually down.

I agree that starting with a good fresh NOOBs SD card would be a good way to see if the green light acts differently.  If it does not then in addition to possible damage to the red LED there might possibly be damage to the SD card socket.

Since the hardware is cheap and available you may want to borrow a friend's for a test or buy a new one.

And finally, make very sure you have a power supply intended for the thing.  Improper power can lead to all sorts of strange indications.  Again, they are cheap and available, so either borrow a known good one or just buy another yourself.

Good luck.

Comment: FYI, LED failures are really rare these days, and usually manifest as gradual brightness loss rather than total failure.

Comment: True, but they use LEDs in the jetliners.  ;-)   Anyway, I would definitely go with a fresh NOOBs card and see if things are any different.

Comment: You guys are really harsh with the downvoting and all.  A simple comment is all that is needed to correct things.  Start a discussion in comments or something.  No reason to trash someone's reputation anonymously like this.  Be positive.  You don't have to upvote.  And what doyou gain by downvoting someone who is trying to get it right?  Just send a word to the wise in the comments and be done with it, or just ignore it.  But don't just do the drive-by downvoting.  That's ghetto, man.  When my kids were young and whining I would always tell them to use their words.  It is much more productive.

Comment: I agree with you (I only downvoted peekaboo here, because his answer is a pure guess), but bear in mind that whoever downvoted you anonymously won't get your message, it's only delivered to people who participated in comments.

Comment: Understood.  By the way, as a coincidence, the red power light soldered onto the center of the board for my sun tracker, just stopped coming on a couple of days ago.  Yet the board is working fine.  It is sealed in a box with a transparent top so I can see it and the lights for the relays that move my panels.  They are working - I see the LEDs light as the motors activate.  Just the central red power light suddenly stopped turning on.  It used to always be on whenever power was applied.  So is this an LED failure?  Yes.  They happen.

Comment: So clearly I didn't deserve the downvotes.

Comment: Sometimes it is best avoiding answers of pure theory.. as you can see there are so many answers here with downvotes (plus deleted answers) The question it self, should have been closed and never allowed for speculative answers. There is not even an aceepted answer so this was just a really bad Q&A - Learn form it.. sometimes its better to avoid open ended questions. Rememeber, stack exchange is about asking and answering as specific as possible. (with nice formatting and pictures help allot too)

Answer (score -3):

Try reformatting the SD card? Could be a SD card corruption.

Comment: What about the red LED not lighting?

Answer (score -3):

If you app. writes the SD card and you power off, it's REALLY EASY to corrupt the file system (just like the 'good old days' of Windows 'ntoskernal missing')

So plug in another SD card with a NOOBS image and see what you get. If that works, you then have the task of recovering your data from your now proven corrupted card (very few people ever make 'backups' of their Pi system, yet the Pi is about 100x more likley to corrupt than any modern Windows PC - but back-up devices for PC's can be found almost anywhere)